# How do I cache messages?

Tags: discord.js

How can I cache messages in discord.js? I wanted to make a reaction roles system, but the event for adding reactions works only for cached messages.
I put this code in the "ready" function:

```
bot.channels.cache.get(channel id).messages.cache.get(message id)
```

This does not work, the event still does not fire.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forcefully cache messages through [`MessageManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch).

```js
// with promises
bot.channels.cache
 .get('channel id')
 .messages.fetch('message id')
 .then(() => {
  console.log(`The message has been cached`);
 });

// with async/await (make sure your function is async)
await bot.channels.cache.get('channel id').messages.fetch('message id');
console.log(`The message has been cached`);
```

Comment: the bot doesnt even start up anymore (i use heroku)

Comment: nevermind, removing the await part fixes it. thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted so it's easier to find for others in the future that share your problem.